# K-homology fundamental class for singular varieties?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology, index-theory

Given a smooth $\text{Spin}^c$ compact manifold without boundary $M$, a suitable normalization of the Dirac operator defines the fundamental class of $M$ in Kasparov's $KK(\mathbb{C}, C^0(M))$. This class is dual to the identity class in $K^0(M)$. Note that every almost complex manifold, in particular, every complex manifold, has a canonical $\text{Spin}^c$ structure.

Question: does a singular compact algebraic variety over $\mathbb{C}$ also have a fundamental class in the analytic K-homology described just as above? I'm happy to add assumptions on the behavior of singularities.